# C / Getting line string from text file and storing them in array/pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to get all lines from the text file and store them in my `char**` pointer (array of strings). The problem is that when I try to set indices for pointer's strings, the program assigns the last scanned sentence for all indices.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 10000


int main()
{   
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    char** lines = (char**) malloc(10000*200*sizeof(char));

    int count = 0;

    fp = fopen("test.txt","r");

    while(fgets(line,10000,fp)) {    
      lines[count] = line; 
      count++;
    } 

    fclose(fp);

    for(int i =0; i<2000;i++){
      printf("%s",lines[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

lets assume test.txt is like this:

```
Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the
bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the
book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in
it, and what is the use of a book, thought Alice without pictures or
conversations?
```

When I print like this, every time I get the last sentence (in this case `conversations?` ) in my text file. However, I want to set every scanned sentence from the text file to the different index in my char**. For example, I want to set like this:

```
lines[0] gives "Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the"
lines[1] gives "bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the"
and so on.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't copy characters from one string buffer to another simply by assigning a pointer (all that does is to make the destination point to the source, as you have noticed).

Instead, you must actually copy the characters, using the `strcpy` function. So, instead of:

```c
    lines[count] = line; // Just makes each pointer point to the same buffer
```

use:

```c
    strcpy(lines[count], line); // Copies the CURRENT contents of "line"
```

You also have a severe problem in the way you are using your `char** lines` buffer. If you want an array of 200 lines, each with a maximum length of 10000 characters, you should allocate them as follows:

```c
char** lines = malloc(200 * sizeof(char*)); // Make 200 pointers
// Now allocate 10000 chars to each of these pointers:
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) lines[i] = malloc(10000 * sizeof(char));
```

Note: The 200 buffers will be uninitialized (contain random data) so, in your print loop, you should only use those you have copied real data to, using the `count` variable as the loop limit:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     printf("%s", lines[i]);
}
```

Also, don't forget to free the memory allocated when you're done:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) free(lines[i]); // Free each line buffer...
free(lines); // ... then free the array of pointers itself
```

Comment: @asgarov You're welcome! You should really also make sure you don't read in too many lines; something like this in the `while` loop: `if (count++ == 200) { printf("Max lines read!\n"); break; }`

Answer (score -1):

strdup resolve the issue, free resources as said by Adrian when finished.

```
int main()
{   
   FILE *fp = NULL;
   char line[MAX_LINE];
   char** lines = (char**) malloc(10000*200*sizeof(char));

   int count = 0;

   fp = fopen("test.txt","r");

   while(fgets(line,10000,fp)) {    
      lines[count] = strdup(line);
      count++;
   } 

   fclose(fp);

   for(int i =0; i<count;i++){
      printf("%s",lines[i]);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) free(lines[i]);
   free(lines);

   return 0;
}
```

If you are looking for better performance look at my repo (https://github.com/PatrizioColomba/strvect)

Comment: Please indent and format the code properly. Currently it is a mess.

Comment: Why exactly 10000?

Comment: better indentation now?

Comment: Double-check the `malloc` call, it is completely wrong.

Comment: Better, but still not good enough. Please try again. Don't manually indent the code, use a tool for that.

Comment: where can i find the tool?